# How to position multiple divs to line up

Tags: html, css

I've got 6 identical divs that I want to line up so that there are 3 rows of 2. How do I do this? If I make them float: left they mess up the layout

HTML:

```
<div id="block">
    <h3>Name</h3>
        <p class="content"><span class="laquo">&nbsp;</span>Review<span class="raquo">&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>

<div id="block">
    <h3>Name</h3>
        <p class="content"><span class="laquo">&nbsp;</span>Review<span class="raquo">&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#block {
background: url(Images/Testimonials/bg.gif);
width: 500px;
padding: 0px 6px 0 6px;
}
```

Comment: Put the relevant code you have so far in your post so that we have a [mcve] to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `float: left`, but give the divs 50% width.
It's always better to put `box-sizing: border-box` so padding and borders won't increase the total width/height (if specified) of the elements.
And don't use the same id multiple times within the same page, convert that to a class.

```css
.block {
  background: url(Images/Testimonials/bg.gif);
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <p class="content"><span class="laquo">&nbsp;</span>Review<span class="raquo">&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <p class="content"><span class="laquo">&nbsp;</span>Review<span class="raquo">&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <p class="content"><span class="laquo">&nbsp;</span>Review<span class="raquo">&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <p class="content"><span class="laquo">&nbsp;</span>Review<span class="raquo">&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <p class="content"><span class="laquo">&nbsp;</span>Review<span class="raquo">&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <p class="content"><span class="laquo">&nbsp;</span>Review<span class="raquo">&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to add a few extra `div`elements, but this will work.

```css
#block {
background: url(Images/Testimonials/bg.gif);
width: 500px;
padding: 0px 6px 0 6px;
}
#table {
  display: table;
}

#tableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

#block {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div id="tableRow">
    <div id="block">
        <h3>Name</h3>
            <p class="content"><span class="laquo">&nbsp;</span>Review<span class="raquo">&nbsp;</span></p>
    </div>

    <div id="block">
        <h3>Name</h3>
            <p class="content"><span class="laquo">&nbsp;</span>Review<span class="raquo">&nbsp;</span></p>
    </div>
  </div> 

  <div id="tableRow">

    <div id="block">
        <h3>Name</h3>
            <p class="content"><span class="laquo">&nbsp;</span>Review<span class="raquo">&nbsp;</span></p>
    </div>

    <div id="block">
        <h3>Name</h3>
            <p class="content"><span class="laquo">&nbsp;</span>Review<span class="raquo">&nbsp;</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div id="tableRow">

    <div id="block">
        <h3>Name</h3>
            <p class="content"><span class="laquo">&nbsp;</span>Review<span class="raquo">&nbsp;</span></p>
    </div>

    <div id="block">
        <h3>Name</h3>
            <p class="content"><span class="laquo">&nbsp;</span>Review<span class="raquo">&nbsp;</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```